# Multer req.files undefined when sending data via axios, but when using Postman all works

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I need to post an array of images and a single image for product preview.
Here my multer settings

```
const multer = require('multer');

// Multer settings
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  // reject a file
  if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});

const multerSettings = upload.fields([{ name: 'thumb', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'images', maxCount: 8 }]);

module.exports = multerSettings;
```

My model for posting data. I am using MongoDB

```
thumb: {
  url: String
},
images: [{url: String}]
```

Client part

```
const fd = new FormData();
const { images, thumb } = state.details;
fd.append('thumb', thumb);
fd.append('images', images);
await this.$axios.post('/product', fd);
```

Images are an array of files [File, File, File], and for some reason, req.files['images'] is undefined on the server, but thumb works properly. And when I am sending the same data via postman all works as expected. In the browser in header preview i see the following data

```
thumb: (binary)
images: [{},{},{}]
```

Maybe images should be an array of binary data?
And when sending a single file like this

```
fd.append('images', images[0]);
```

req.files['images'] its work properly. I need somehow modify my array on the client. By i have no idea what i should do.

I would be grateful for any tips

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple.

```
const fd = new FormData();
const { images, thumb } = state.details;
fd.append('thumb', thumb);;
for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   fd.append('images', images[i]);
}
await this.$axios.post('/product', fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const files = new FormData();
    files.append('files', data);

    const res = await httpApi.post('/user/upload', files, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}});
```

This works! :)